# how do i improve the temperature of my sons room?

Tags: insulation, attic

i have a house in new york and i have insulation with paper backing in the attic. My room which has the thermostat is always 4 degrees warmer than his room which is situated over the living room can i just temporarily put 6 mil plastic in the attic over my sons room to keep the heat in until i can afford to double the insulation in the attic?

Comment: Although poor attic insulation can definitely be a major contributor to heat loss, it seems less obvious to me that this is the source of the problems if other upstairs rooms are significantly different temperatures. You should check for other obvious drafts (electrical outlets, windows) and other places where heat can be lost (outside walls, or especially windows). It might be worth buying an infrared thermometer (can be found online for as little as ~$20) which will make it easier to find cold spots around the room, as well as compare different rooms to each other.

Comment: the heating source is forced air and i used the thermal sensor and portable thermometer but no drafts house is 8 years old

Answer (score 2):

What is your heating method? Most are somewhat adjustable, though this may not be obvious if you don't know what to look for (i.e. baseboard hot water generally has a flap that can be open, partially closed, or fully closed on the top section of the baseboard, which affects heat delivery.)

If you turn up the heat delivery in the room that is colder, and/or close it down in the room that is warmer, the room temperatures should become closer.

Not sure where you are going with the plastic - 6 mil plastic is not an effective insulator. If you have attic access and can't afford to "double the insulation" go buy what you **can** afford (6 mil plastic costs money - spend that money on insulation instead) and put it over his room, if that is feasible. If money is really tight you may be able to get help with insulation from a heating assistance program or by asking for leftover insulation (most people who do an insulation project end up with some) on craigslist.

Another alternative would be to swap rooms (so you take the colder one if you are concerned about your son being too cold) and throw on some extra blankets.

**Edit: since you have forced air heat**, partially close the vent or vents supplying the warmer room with the thermostat. If there are not built-in louvers to do this, place a book or board over part of the vent, or tape something over part of it if it's a wall vent. This should reduce the rate of heat delivery to that room, so the system wll run a little longer to heat it up to the setpoint on the thermostat, and by doing that, the other room will become warmer relative to the room with the thermostat. You could also have a HVAC professional adjust this deeper in the duct system - but in general we as end-users lacking certain tools and information the HVAC pro has should **not** start adjusting dampers (in the ducts) willy-nilly (it's fine to open any louvers (on the vent) in the son's room and close them in your room, or to **block** vents in your room - "opening up" a system too much can burn out the main fan motor (this is a counterintuitive but important point - blocking of vents reduces the load on the central fan - opening them up too much can overload it.)

In general, what you are describing is a system with poorly balanced heat delivery, which a good HVAC technician should be a be able to correct. But you can do a lot of it yourself by closing down or partially blocking vents in all the "too warm" rooms until the "too cold" rooms are warmer.

Comment: last winter i moved the thermostat to his room but the whole house was hot and the bills let me know that option wont work ,the furnace is in the basement and it blows the air two stories then pass my room and then to his room by the time it gets to his its too cold i had to move all the kids 3 of them to the room before the air reaches  my room and they are outgrowing each other the house has 4 bedrooms and am now only using two the other over the garage is 8 degrees colder i checked up there nothing is disconnected

Comment: the heating source is forced air and i used the infrared thermometer and the portable room thermometer  no major drafts the  house is 8 years old its r30 with paper faced on the sheetrock in the attic i just wanted to know  whats the cheapest temp alternative than spending 3k on insulation in a house i plan to move out of next year and at the same time avoid the 600 per month utility bills. im open to putting comforters in the attic over his room at least ill have the comforters when i move.

Comment: i know putting 6 mil plastic over drafty windows help make a room warmer thats why i thought about spreading it over his room in the attic because thats accesible and we all know hot air rises. so what do you guys suggest.

Comment: There shouldn't be any drafts (and you say there are no drafts) from an 8 year old house up into the attic. Those should all be stopped at the ceiling level. If you want to spread something over the colder room(s) in the attic, 15" wide by 25 ft long unfaced R30 fiberglass is all of $14 bucks a roll. Takes a BIG house (roughly 7000 square feet) to eat up $3000 that way. Comforters go on the bed, not in the attic. Adequate insulation should help in selling the house.

Comment: i got the 3k quote from a insulation company to do the whole attic  but 15 x 25unfaced r30 $14 bucks  i hope 6 rolls can do the trick for his 14x16 room ill try a few rolls on wed thanks

Comment: Rooms over the garage? There's a red flag. Builders (even in current houses) sadly, often get this wrong. They (poorly) insulate the garage ceiling, then leave a space between that and the floor. This space often gets heated, in order to make the floor slightly warmer (and as you can imagine, this is horribly inefficient). Sometimes there is an air return (which means any leaks from the garage circulate car exhaust around the house), sometimes not (which means the heating is doing basically nothing). I really hope the attic insulation helps, but you may have bigger troubles, sadly.